# How to include CMake lib/projects in other Visual Studio projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I don't have any experience with CMake, but I downloaded an API from Github that was CMake-based.

I can build it in Visual Studio and I did the Install in CMake menu. 
But can I cannot seem to add the CMake library in any of my other projects (C++ projects). I have tried looking all around but in all documentation there seems to be no answer (or at least simple answer).

Comment: Hi. Once a CMake-using library is built & installed, it does not differ from any other non-CMake library (at least when the consuming project doesn't use CMake). Can you elaborate on why CMake is causing issues for you, and how you feel it differs from using a non-CMake library?

Comment: I get the feeling that OP wants to add the Cmake project to a pre-existing VS solution rather than simply use a pre-built library.

Comment: well either, I get the part that Visual studio cant add it to another solution just yet, maybe in the future. but visual studio is not allowing me to add the .lib that is generated or add the <name.h> is that is usually available for C++ projects

Answer (score 0):

You could use cmake to generate a Visual Studio project and then add that project to your solution.